# jQuery render datepicker and text underneath in a dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to create a dialog box in jQuery, inside the dialog box I want to render datepicker and then some text underneath. I have the following code:

```
<div id="dialog">
 <p>Delivery methods</p>

</div>
```

and my jQuery:

```
$j('document').ready(function(){

      $j('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 500,
            modal: true,

          });

    // Dialog Link
    $j('#delivery_date').click( function(e) {   
      e.preventDefault();
      // opens the dialog
      $j('#dialog').dialog('open');
    });
  });

$j(function() {
  $j( "#dialog" ).datepicker({
      numberOfMonths: 2, 
      altField: ".dialog", 
      altFormat: "DD, d MM, yy",
      showButtonPanel: true
    });
});
```

I have the dialog box rendering datepicker inside of it but I can't figure out how to add some text underneath. More specifically I want to have some radio buttons underneath datepicker, inside the dialog box.

Any guidance on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can append whatever html you want to your div, like this:

```
var dialog = document.getElementById("dialog");
dialog.innerHTML = dialog.innerHTML + "<p>...</p>";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this allows me to add some text to my dialog box underneath datepicker. The only problem is that is stops datepicker from working. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: hmm, you can create a div with any content you wish and append it with following methods: document.createElement() and appendChild()